# Issue with calling c:import tag

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, jsp-tags, vs-web-application-project

I have two web application. one is running under XXXX server port and another application is running under YYYY port.

I am trying to get content from XXXX port in YYYY port. Generally it can be done by using iframe or c:import tag

Here i have used jsp tag(c:import) top get content from XXXX port. There is no problem with rendering the content from different application. The issue here is with rendering images and css files.

example `<c:import var="test" url="http://localhost:XXXX/test-content.html"/> ${test}`

test-content.html file has some text, images and some css in header section. the path of the images would be /images/base and css path would be /css/common/

Obviously YYYY port does not have the above hierarchy structure so that images and css are not coming.

Of course, It will work if i maintain the same hierarchy structure in YYYY port. It will be very difficult to maintain the same hierarchy structure in both servers

Is there any way to include that images and css files without maintaining/creating it in YYYY port?

I am looking for a solution to get content from different web application without maintaining the hierarchy structure.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not about  usage, but about application architecture. If you want to share static resources (images, css) between two apps, put them into some shared place, which could be dedicated http server or third application in the same web server (your two apps will then have the same URLs to these resources).